# how to reverse a hash in perl without using built in function?

Tags: perl

```
1) %hash = (
    1 => 'a',
    4 => 'g',
    7 => 'h'
```

);

WAP to reverse of the given hash without using reverse function?

Comment: Write your homeworks on your own.

Comment: And why this bizarre limitation?

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicate values? E.g. if `1 => 'a'` and `11 => 'a'` then only one of them will become a key, e.g. `'a' => 11`

Comment: I guess it should have the same behavior as [reverse](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html), which removes duplicates.

Comment: please. read. documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really learn Perl - it is really fun when you learn it yourself.

It is really that simple:

```
my %rev;
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    $rev{$hash{$key}} = $key;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to interchange the values and keys. I simply want o/p like this  \n    %hash = (
    7 => 'h'
    4 => 'g',
    1 => 'a',
);

Comment: That is not possible. Hashes in Perl are NOT ordered by definition. And BTW, this code is equivalent to embedded `reverse` function.

Comment: @WaseemShaikh You cannot sort a hash. Or rather, you can sort its keys and values, but you cannot *store* the sorting order in the hash itself. If you want the keys in a specific order, use an array. E.g. `my @order = qw(7 4 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

TIMTOWTDI:

```
my %a = ( foo => 1, bar => 2 );    # original hash
my @a = %a;                        # copy to array
my @rev;                           # reversed list container
push @rev, pop @a while @a;        # fill @rev from the back forward
my %rev = @rev;                    # assign reversed list to hash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %by_letter;
@by_letter{ values(%by_num) } = keys(%by_num);
```

or

```
my %by_letter = map { $by_num{$_} => $_ } keys(%by_num);
```